# ElementClickInterceptedException: </button> is not clickable at point (470, 236)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this Angular code which I want to test by automating click action:

```
<mobileweb-tab-container-item _ngcontent-qoc-c24="" _nghost-qoc-c27="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!----><!---->
   <a _ngcontent-qoc-c27="" href="null" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <div _ngcontent-qoc-c27="" class="icon-box" fxlayout="column" fxlayoutalign="space-evently center" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; place-content: center flex-start; align-items: center;">
         <img _ngcontent-qoc-c27="" class="icon" id="outbound.pick.load.image" src="assets/img/outbound/pick/load.jpg">
         <div _ngcontent-qoc-c27="" class="icon-label" id="outbound.pick.load.image.label">Load</div>
      </div>
   </a>
</mobileweb-tab-container-item>
```

Full source: https://pastebin.com/BbKbarPH

I use this code to automate the click action:

First select the tab:

```
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(tabId)))).click().build().perform();
```

Second click on icon:

```
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
        System.out.println("Click on Icon " + name + " using id locator " + iconId);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(iconId)));
        webElement.click();
```

The issue is that sometimes the element is not found. For example:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image (tried for 25 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.mobile.accessorial.charge.AccessorialChargeTest.accessorialChargeTest(AccessorialChargeTest.java:161)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#warehouse\.all\.accessorial\-charge\.image"}
(Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.159)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DTXA-ENVTEST01', ip: '10.100.35.181', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 92.0.4515.159, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553..., userDataDir: C:\Users\devadmin\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54247}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 9c789c51f703a81f1d1ac2b0ac792bba
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image}
at org.mobile.accessorial.charge.AccessorialChargeTest.accessorialChargeTest(AccessorialChargeTest.java:161)
```

During tab load there is a animation to load tabs and icons. Is there some other way to implement a listener which will wait for the components to fully load and perform click action?

Comment: Your title is not a question, it's a partial error message which isn't that helpful. Also, the error message in your title is the only place you mention that error message and you mention a *different* error message in your question. Which error message are you getting with your current code? You never indicate which element you are trying to click. You aren't showing your locators, you just show variable names but never the assignment. Why are you using `Actions` in your first code block when all you are doing is clicking? Just use the same code as a the second click, `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: You need to clarify and simplify your question. See [mcve] and [help]. Please edit your question and narrow the focus to the actual issue you are having... describe that clearly. Then add the code you are using that results in the error, clearly indicating which line is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add visiblity and clickable waits in your code,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By appct = By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(appct));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(appct)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExpectedConditions` to wait until the animation element disappears with

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

command where `element` is the animation element `By` locator.
The `By` locator here can be any locator type used by Selenium.
Something like the following:

```
By.cssSelector("div.className")  
By.xpath("//div[@id='theId']")
By.id("theId")
```

etc.
So that some particular case can look like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'animation')]")));
```

Alternatively you can click the element with JavaScript even if it is covered by some other element (animation) with

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

But this approach is not recommended and should be used only if no alternatives can be found since this doesn't imitate real user actions.

Comment: Can you extend the first example a little bit please?

Answer (score 0):

See as mentioned by @Prophet, you can check for `invisibilityOfElementLocated`, however you should look for visibility of the element right after it's load/Animation invisibility.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id of animation icon")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(tabId))).click();
```

In case all you are looking for a listener to implement :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement animation= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath of animation")));
WebElement tab = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(tabId)));
beforeClickOn(tab , driver);
tab.click();
afterClickOn(tab, driver);
```

in whichever class you are writing this, extends that class from `AbstractWebDriverEventListener`

Comment: also I could not find `warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image` in the shared HTML